# How to document returned data in JsDoc

Tags: javascript, json, jsdoc

How can I document the returned JSON result of a request to a server?

Example

```
/**
 * Gets a user's data
 * @returns {jQuery}
 */
function getUserData(userId){
   return $.get('/usr/' + userId);
}
```

In the above example the returned data would be an object of JSON such as

```
{
   "name" : "Bob",
   "status" : 2
}
```

Comment: *"In the above example the returned data would be an object of JSON such as"* No it won't. `$.get` is synchronous. It actually returns a `jqXHR` object. Also a JavaScript object is not JSON.

Comment: Yes I know. That is the point of my question and why it says "returns jQuery". I would like to provide the data that can be returned with this result if there is a standard way, but I cannot find it in jsdoc examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/**
 * Gets a user's data request
 * @return {jQuery.jqXHR}
 */
function getUserData(userId){
   return $.getJSON('/usr/' + userId);
}

/*
 * Handles the result of a user data request.
 * @param {Object} data The JSON object, already converted to an Object.
 */
function doSomethingWithUserData(data) {
  console.log('do something with user data:', data);
}

getUserData(userId).done(handleUserData);
```

As Felix points out, the return value is not JSON, it's not even an Object.

Quote [JQuery's types documentation](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR):

> As of jQuery 1.5, the $.ajax() method returns the jqXHR object, which is a superset of the XMLHTTPRequest object. For more information, see the jqXHR section of the $.ajax entry

Since `$.get` and `$.getJSON` are both shorthands for `$.ajax`, the same applies.

In the example I'm using the promise and a handler. I've made a function from the handler so it could be documented more clearly, but this is often done with an anonymous function.

I've also converted `$.get` to `$.getJSON`, which will do the `JSON.parse` call for you (which converts the reply from a string to an object). `$.get`'s handler would take a `@param {string}` instead.

**Update**

*In a comment OP asked how to handle this with custom data so that a future dev would know what to expect in the call.*

Now that we've got the data, let's look at documenting it.

There are 3 good solutions for documentation, depending on complexity and if you have initialization to do.

The simplest would be to create a @typedef using @property to describe the properties, this requires no additional code, and is purely documentation.

```
goog.provide('UserData');
/* 
 * UserData (in the style of Closure's JSDocs)
 * @typedef {{
 *   name: {string},
 *   title: {string}
 * }}
 */
UserData;
```

or

```
/* 
 * UserData (in the style of useJSDocs)
 * @typedef {Object}
 * @property {string} name
 * @property {string} title
 */
var UserData;
```

in use:

```
/*
 * Handles the result of a user data request.
 * @param {UserData} data The JSON object, already converted to an Object,
 * cast to UserData
 */
function doSomethingWithUserData(data) {
  console.log('do something with user data:', data);
}
```

And [@interface @record](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Structural-Interfaces-in-Closure-Compiler) which is similar and may be more useful to you.

Finally there's a straight up class, where you'd `let user = new UserData(jsonUser)`, if you can gather up more than a few lines of default setting / initialization and place it in the class, this is how I'd suggest going.

Comment: Here's my situation, maybe i should have it mode clear: Suppose a file has 100 "getFromServer" functions just like `getUserData`. How is a new developer to know what is going to be returned from each ajax request? What if they have no access to server code?

Comment: Hmm.. each response as a class. I suppose that could work. In your example, how can you be writing `UserData` without the script breaking?

Comment: @BarryBones41 Sorry about that, i've updated the examples to include declarations. I'm so used to goog.provide that I completely missed this when writing the answer, so I've included an example of goog.provide as well.

Comment: For the `UserData (in the style of useJSDocs)` example, you have an extraneous `}}` at the end

Comment: @lambart Thanks! Fixed!